# json doesn't install despite all i have done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, windows

I have been trying to solve this for days but i still cannot figure it out. JSON is still not installing. i will appreciate your help

```
C:\Users\Max Billionaire>gem install json --no-rdoc --no-ri
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json 1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160417-268-iqr9ay.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
cc1.exe: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction

Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net> for instructions.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/json-
1.8.3/gem_make.out`
```

Comment: Are you using RubyInstaller?

Comment: yes i'm using ruby installer

Comment: rails has installed correctly but json is still not.

Comment: Have you installed RubyInstaller's DevKit?

Comment: yes i have installed devkit, run "ruby dk.rb init" and "ruby dk.rb install" and it both worked but json is not installing

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042900/ruby-json-gem-install-error-ruby-2-4-1-json-1-8-6-windows-10?rq=1?