# Ruby JSON gem install error: Ruby 2.4.1, JSON 1.8.6 (Windows 10)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Running `gem install json` and receiving the following error

```
Fetching: json-1.8.6.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
      1 [main] make 8392 child_info_fork::abort: C:\msys32\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x30000) != child(0x20000)
      1 [main] make 332 child_info_fork::abort: C:\msys32\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x20000) != child(0x30000)
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170904-8096-t8xlbq.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean
      1 [main] make 8392 child_info_fork::abort: C:\msys32\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x30000) != child(0x20000)
make: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
      1 [main] make 332 child_info_fork::abort: C:\msys32\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x20000) != child(0x30000)
make: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
```

Using

- Ruby 2.4.1
- Windows 10 (x64)

Can't find any posts on Google or here.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby 2.4 relies on json >= 2.0](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2015-09-11-200) and you are attempting to install json 1.8.6. They are incompatible. Ensure the two versions are compatible then retry your operation.

Comment: Marked as the correct answer. Windows doesn't support the necessary version of JSON which is whyt he question was raised, but this answer is nonetheless true.